# How do I only display contents within<body></body> using file_get_contents

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I have a code that is grabbing the entire results page of a search from a database.  I want to only grab and display the contents within the body tags so that I can manipulate the rest of the results page myself.  Please advise. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `DOMDocument` to extract the parts of the page that you want.

```
$html = file_get_contents("some resource");
libxml_use_internal_errors(true); //Prevents Warnings, remove if desired
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$body = "";
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName("body")->item(0)->childNodes as $child) {
    $body .= $dom->saveHTML($child);
}
echo $body;
```